# Laravel. redirects between subdomains

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, laravel-5

I would like to redirect all the URL with or without www to a specific subdomain.

Example: 
`example.com` and `www.example.com` to `cn.example.com`

I saw some people say by editing the .htaccess file in public will do, this is what have in my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this rule below `rewriteengine` on,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?\.example.com
RewriteRule ^ cn.example.com [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

This preserves the request path and the parameters:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^$ subdomain.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]`